# Convert a Gem to a Plugin in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I currently have a gem installed on my development machine. Now that I want to use this gem on the production but I could not install it due to some issue with the server. Is there a way that I can convert this gem to a plugin so that I can transfer it to the server?

if no, is there a way to transfer this gem from my machine to the server?

BTW, I'm using an old version of Ruby on Rails (2.1)

Thanks.

Comment: What gem is it? Does it use native extensions?

Comment: Please note that plugin support will be removed in rails 4

Comment: @Maz - ambethia-smtp-tls

Comment: @JaredBeck yeah I know that plugin is already obsolete but the app is in 2.1 and unfortunately, I'm accessing the server remotely and internet access is limited so I could not install the gem. That is why I'm having troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the gem's single source code file into your project's lib directory. https://github.com/ambethia/smtp-tls/blob/master/lib/smtp-tls.rb

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the plugin is compatible with Rails 2.1 you should be able to move the plugin to your `/vendor` directory, and it should work from there. As mentioned in the comments, the vendor directory is going to be removed and that style of plugins will be removed in Rails 4, but for Rails 2.1 that doesn't matter.

To get the files, go on `rubygems.org` and find the project homepage. You can probably find the source code for the plugin you're interested in (including a version that's compatible with Rails 2.x) on Github, then just clone it to your vendor directory.

Comment: well, it is a gem and I could not find any plugin version. I could not also find a gem file (*.gem) that I can use to install it locally.

Anyway, for the sake of documentation over the net, what I did is to copy the all the gem related files found on my local gem directory and put it on the server's gem directory. That did the trick.

Comment: What about its dependencies?  Won't removing the gem risk losing the dependencies?  And if you copy them then won't this risk collision with those from other gems?

Comment: Well yes, those are potential problems. That's basically why Bundler has been adopted in favor of the old vendored plugins approach. However, based on the OPs comments it looks like he was able to just move all the gems into his project directory and things worked alright.